# SQL Set column with Key and max value from other colum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, database-cursor, temporal

I need update the column 'max_register' according to the max value from column 'duration' of the same Id, set the value = 1, and the others values = 0.

Initial table:

```
Id | duration | max_register
1  |  0       | 0
1  |  7       | 0
1  |  3       | 0
2  |  10      | 0
2  |  5       | 0
2  |  0       | 0
3  |  6       | 0
3  |  5       | 0
3  |  0       | 0
```

Ending table:

```
Id | duration | max_register
1  |  0       | 0
1  |  7       | 1
1  |  3       | 0
2  |  10      | 1
2  |  5       | 0
2  |  0       | 0
3  |  6       | 1
3  |  5       | 0
3  |  0       | 0
```

This is a temporal table, with thousand of registers. So I dont know if is necesary use a cursor or something like that.

Comment: are you using mysql 8 or something earlier?

Comment: What is a  temporal table? Do you mean temporary table?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2017

Answer (score 1):

in mysql 5.7+ :

```
update tablename t1
set max_register = 1
where (id, duration)  = ( 
                          select id, duration 
                          from tablename t2
                          where t1.id = t2.id 
                          order by t2.duration limit 1
)
```

in sql server , if you have  a date column , you can use this query:

```
update  t
set max_register = 1
from ( 
   select max_register , row_number() over (partition by id order by duration desc, dateCol desc) rn 
   from tablename
) t where  t.rn = 1
```

Comment: It isn't a fault with this nice solution, more of a business decision/rule:  What happens in cases of ties- two records in a group with the max duration of 5?  There may need to be a business decision rule run for cleaning ties and selecting a single max duration before flagging it.

Comment: @mikeY well with your current table structure you can’t .you need to have a unique key in your table

Comment: In case of two or more records with the same value, the second filter used is base on other column called 'date', take the more recient data.

Comment: @eshirvana  It isn't my data and I'm not OP. I was just trying to point out that if OP has a case where there are two records with ID 3 which each have a duration value of 6, that OP will need to be prepared to deal with that.  OP seems to have a date field we don't see to handle things.

Comment: @mikeY Sorry I thought it’s your question

Comment: @inec seeupdated answer